# How to use CsvHelper TypeConverter to Format to two decimals?

Tags: c#, export, csvhelper, typeconverter

I am using CsvHelper for export, and I'd like to have the text of numbers with two decimals in the output.

I've read the pages on CsvHelper, including Typeconverters but I can't find an example of what I think is pretty simple, and Typeconvers
I tried:

```
Map(m => m.DonationAmount).TypeConverterOption.NumberStyles(NumberStyles.Currency);
```

But that didn't seem to have any effect.

I also tried

```
Map(m => m.DonationAmount.ToString("0.00"));
```

which just errored right out.

I imagine its something simple that I'm missing.

(If it matters, I'm only writing, not reading CSVs with these maps.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
Map(m => m.DonationAmount).TypeConverterOption.Format("0.00");
```

[`TypeConverterOption.Format`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/30.0.1/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/MemberMapTypeConverterOption.cs#L79) sets:

> The string format to be used when type converting.

Notes:

- [`TypeConverterOption.NumberStyles`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/30.0.1/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/MemberMapTypeConverterOption.cs#L68) does not work because, as of the most recent version (30.0.1), [`DecimalConverter`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/30.0.1/src/CsvHelper/TypeConversion/DecimalConverter.cs) does not override [`DefaultTypeConverter.ConvertToString()`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/30.0.1/src/CsvHelper/TypeConversion/DefaultTypeConverter.cs#L41) and so the number number style is not used at all when formatting.  And, while [`DoubleConverter`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/30.0.1/src/CsvHelper/TypeConversion/DoubleConverter.cs#L26) does override `ConvertToString()`, it doesn't use `memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.NumberStyles`.

  Both converters do override `ConvertFromString()` and use `TypeConverterOptions.NumberStyles` inside, so the number style does indeed get used when reading a CSV file.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aqWplL).

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you.

For added searching later -- here's how I made SQL nulls not appear as 0 in an integer column - `Map(m => m.NextOfKinContactID).TypeConverterOption.Format("0;;' '");`

Comment: We have a list of thank=yous and credits in our about page (the project is for a national non-profit). Would you like to be acknowledged?

Comment: @bph - sure, thanks, but you would need to credit my account since I post here pseudonymously, is that OK?  If that would be a nuisance, then no need thanks.

Comment: Sure (by your name on here is fine). I'm one of those who thinks SO should have some more private messaging but I get whey they don't. You can ping me on linked in if you want to be less anonymous. https://www.linkedin.com/in/byronhynes/

Comment: For others like me who forget that their default handler for csv files is probably Excel... remember that Excel doesn't show .00 when it imports a csv. "Open with Code" is your friend.